# Cauchy Integral Formula and Dirichlet Series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Can someone explain to me this step from Harold Davenports 'Multiplicative Number Theory'?

\begin{equation}
    \psi(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{s}}
\end{equation}
 Since $\psi(s)$ is analytic for $\sigma> \frac{1}{2}$, it has expansion in powers of s-2 with radius of convergence at least $\frac{3}{2}$. This power series is
 \begin{equation}
     \psi(s) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}\psi^{(m)}(2)(s-2)^m
 \end{equation}

I assume we use Cauchy's Integral formula but I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\psi$ is an analytic function whose domain is $\Omega=\left\{z\in\mathbb C\,\middle|\,\operatorname{Re}z>\frac12\right\}$. For each $z_0\in\Omega$ there is a power series centered at $z_0$ which converges to $\psi(z)$ whose radius of convergence is at least the distance from $z_0$ to the boundary of $\Omega$. In the case of $2$, that distance is $\frac32$.

This is a general property of analytic functions: if the domain is $\Omega$ and if $z_0\in\Omega$, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of the function centered at $z_0$ is at least the distance from $z_0$ to the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Obrigado. Yes I understand now thank you very much. Do you know how to calculate this  $\psi^{(m)}(2)$ in this step?
    $\psi^{(m)}(2) = (-1)^m \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (\text{log}n)^m n^{-2}=(-1)^m b_m
$

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: done! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601372/termwise-differentiation-of-a-term-in-an-analytic-series

Comment: @gnarm This "general property of analytic functions" is a consequence of the Cauchy integral formula, expanding $\frac1{z-s}$ as a power series in $z/s$